# NP-completeness of Induced disjoint paths between a set of sources and a set of sinks

Tags: np-complete, reductions, np, polynomial-time-reductions

In a given undirected graph $G(V,E)$, a set of $k$ paths is said to be induced if:

1. They are vertex-disjoint.
2. Each one is itself an induced path.
3. No edge connects two vertices of two different paths.

Given a set of sources $\{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$ and a set of sink $\{t_1,\dots,t_k\}$, a set of $k$ path connecting the given sources to the given sinks is such a set of paths that:

1. For each source $s_i$, there exists exactly one path that connects it to some sink $t_j$
2. For each sink $t_j$, there exists exactly one path that connects some source $s_i$ to it.

> **Input**: A graph $G(V,E)$ and a set of $k$ sources $\{s_1,\dots,s_n\}$  and a set of $k$ sinks $\{t_1,\dots,t_k\}$
>
> **Output**: **YES** if there exists (a set of) $k$ induced paths connecting $\{s_1,\dots,s_k\}$ to $\{t_1,\dots,t_k\}$ for every $1\leq i\leq k$, **NO** otherwise.

Is this problem NP-complete?

Note that there is a related earlier [question here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/109952/472), but its input is slightly different.

Comment: Did you check if my construction works for this problem as well? It might.